# Boot options missing after using efibootmgr

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, boot-order, efibootmgr

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Samsung laptop, in which I've successfully installed Ubuntu in the past. After disabling Fast BIOS mode (which enables Legacy Mode), and disabling Secure Boot, the bootable USB I created using Startup Disk creator was recognized, and I was able to start the installation process.

Right before installation began, a dialog came up asking if I wanted to force UEFI installation. Since it said that doing so was only an issue when dualbooting (not my case), I went forward. After the installation, the drive failed to boot (went to a Grub2 prompt), though I was still able to enter the Live USB (which I did, and reinstalled a couple times to see if it worked).

After reading a bit online, I tried using efibootmgr to set the correct partition as the boot partition, using --bootorder. I only passed a single option in the boot order, the ubuntu partition.

From this point on, the Boot Order menu on the BIOS only lists a single entry (ubuntu), which doesn't work any more (the computer simply shuts down), and the Live USB entry never shows up. I've tried enabling Secure Boot, forcing UEFI mode, CSM mode, changing AHCI, etc., and get the same results.

I'm at a loss, since I'm not even able to get the Live USB to run, and therefore don't even have access to a prompt. Ideas on how to move forward?

Comment: Redo the USB. Because you said you weren't able to run the installed system you were then running efibotmgr from a the live session at that probably messed it up.

Comment: I forgot to add, I've already tried rebuilding the Live USB, and run into the same issue (it is not listed as a boot entry).

Comment: Reset UEFI then.

Comment: Did you tried by making USB bootable in  DD mode.